# What happens when an alkylborane is treated with acetic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organoboron-compounds

In the hydroboration reactions of alkenes I've seen so far, they were always [followed by oxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroboration%E2%80%93oxidation_reaction) with $\ce{H2O2/NaOH}$ (to yield alcohols).

Today I found a peculiar reaction in which acetic acid-d<sub>1</sub> was added after hydroboration to give a deuterated product:

[image: Formation of (1R,2R)-1-methylcyclohexane-2-d from 1-methylcyclohex-1-ene]

I don't quite understand what exactly happens after the hydroboration part. Can someone enlighten me here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Acetic acid effects protonolysis of the borane:

[image: Mechanism for borane protonolysis]

If AcOD is used then RD (instead of RH) is formed.